# Qual a melhor forma de armazenar data de cadastro de usuário no banco de dados mysql ? devo usar now()? unix_timestamp()?

Tags: mysql

Eu estava utilizando esse código para fazer isso mas parece que ele não funciona! além disso quando pergunto a melhor forma é pensando nas possiveis dificuldades que terei no futuro como sou iniciante provavelmente deve existir alguma boa pratica para armazenar esse tipo de informação no banco de dados mas não conheço ainda.

```
timecreated timestamp not null default unix_timestamp()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É preciso entender melhor os tipos e suas características para poder responder a isso:

***DATA TYPE:***

- `now()` retorna um tipo `DATETIME`;
- `unix_timestamp()` um tipo `INT`;

**TAMANHO:**

- `DATETIME` por padrão ocupa 5 bytes + segundos ou 8 bytes dependendo da versão do `mysql`
- `INT` por padrão ocupa 4 bytes

***TIME ZONE***

- `DATETIME` armazena a data e o *timezone*
- `TIMESTAMP` ou `INT` quando convertido para `TIMESTAMP` (por exemplo, usando `unix_timestamp()`), "converte usando o fuso horário UTC atual configurado no servidor, e depois converte novamente usando o fuso horário UTC configurado no servidor"(1), ou seja, não preserva o *timezone*.

***RANGE* DE VALORES**

- `DATETIME` segundo a documentação (1), valores entre  '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' a '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'
- `TIMESTAMP` ou `INT` quando convertido para `TIMESTAMP` segundo a documentação (1), valores entre '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'

**RESUMO**

- `DATETIME` ocupa mais espaço, mas preserva a data com UTC original, não faz conversões para ler/gravar, usado para qualquer data;
- `TIMESTAMP`, ocupa menos espaço, implicitamente sempre converte de/para o UTC corrente, tem um *range* mais restrito de datas, usado para datas nesse intervalo, e se o UTC não for um problema, por exemplo para saber se um registro é mais novo/antigo que a data atual, etc.

(1) da [documentação do `mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) :

> "MySQL **converts** TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
> storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
> (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)"

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado Ricardo de coração!! eu apliquei o now como o projeto é usado no node não sei se terei problemas! mas obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: não esqueça de votar na resposta se ele foi util, e boa sorte ;)

Comment: ela foi muito util estou aprendendo a usar a plataforma como faço para votar?